# dateFromString prints out "(null)"

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know that there are lots of questions about this, but none of the answers seem to be working for me. Here's my code (iOS SDK 6.0)

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter alloc];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale];
NSDate *TERMIN = [NSDate alloc];
TERMIN = [df dateFromString:T]; //'T' is date in string NSLog(...,T) is 2002-05-05
```

When I output `TERMIN` through `NSLog` the output is `(null)`

Comment: Is the string in T always this format or does it depend on local settings? If it is always yyyy-MM-dd, why do you set any locale?

Comment: T is allwas yyyy-MM-dd. tried to set locale, because im kind of running out of options here... :D

Comment: No need for the locale, timezone, or formatter behavior. And no need to call `alloc` on `NSDate`. Just assign directly: `NSDate *TERMIN = [df dateFromString:T];`. Confirm `T` is non-nil when this code is run;

Comment: For sanity's sake, I'd add a NSLog("Date string is: \"%@\"",T); just before the dateFromString

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the NSDateFormatter object

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
```

Comment: Damn, i fogot. But output is still null

Answer (score 0):

OK this is kinda akward, i was NSLoging like object.variable instead of [object getVariable] from outside...that was the whole problem. Sorry to bother you guys, im such a dumb*ss :D

Another problem showed up that the code above turns 2002-05-05 into 2002-05-04. But that is for another story i guess...